# How do I get a local variable value in whmcs hook?

Tags: hook, whmcs

How do I get a  local variable value in whmcs hook?

$additionalFieldOne = "123";

```
add_hook('AdminClientDomainsTabFields', 1, function($vars) {

    return array("Domain State"=>$additionalFieldOne);  

});
```

variable $additionalFieldOne in hook function not return value
please help me

Answer (score 1):

The variable *additionalFieldOne* is outside the method;so it is out of scope; put it inside the method, or use `global` variable or use session..

```
global $additionalFieldOne;
$additionalFieldOne="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
add_hook('AdminClientDomainsTabFields',1,function($vars){
    global $additionalFieldOne;
    return array("Domain State"=>$additionalFieldOne);
    });
```